# Minify JS and CSS per directory

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, angularjs

I am looking to minify all of my .js and .css files for my site. They are located in a few separate directories and there are a lot of them. I am looking to use this [Minify](https://code.google.com/p/minify/) code.

Using the minify builder, I can manually add each .js and .css file to the string or I can combine them into an array as a group in the groupsConfig.php file.

That is all manual per file, and when .js files are added/removed/changed a lot from all of the developers the groupsConfig.php arrays get difficult to keep up with.

Is there a way to use minify to dynamically grab all .js or .css files from a particular directory and minify them? This way I won't have to worry about keeping the groupsConfig.php file up to date. I could just specify the js directories and that's the end of the config.

I'm also open to suggestions for other code to use instead of [Minify](https://code.google.com/p/minify/). I am looking to minimize all .js and .css files to help SEO of my site. I am utilizing straight javascript, jquery, and angularjs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like using grunt

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify#compiling-all-files-in-a-folder-dynamically

http://gruntjs.com/installing-grunt if you need to know how to install it

Comment: I am looking closer to using Grunt now for these tasks. I can utilize Chef recipes to have Node.js and Grunt installed automatically on my server. I can also run Grunt tasks from the Chef recipes. I will begin testing it.

Do you also use Grunt to handle your caching? Any recommendations on that part?

Answer (score 0):

You can use gulpJs to do this task. All about the minify, concatenation of files into single `min.js` also acceptable. There are so many features you can use. Here is my repo [gulpJs code for references](https://github.com/metallurgical/myGulpJs), just use that `gulpfile.js` to do all of this. Just wanna say, my gulpjs code is not good enough to cover everything but good for your reference.

**Official Site**
 [GulpJs](http://gulpjs.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the option and reference. I actually started to use Grunt because I can easily use it with chef recipes on our AWS infrastructure.